# Is there a fast way to compare one element in a numpy array to the rest of the elements in that array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array, and I want to see if any element in that array is greater than or equal to any other element in that array. I could do two for loops, but my array has a length of 10,000 or greater, and so that created a very slow program. Anyway I can do this faster?

[EDIT] I only need it to see if it's greater than or equal to the elements that come after the element I am looking at, and if it is, I need to know it's index.

[EDIT]
I am going to re-explain my problem more clearly, because the current solutions aren't working for what I am needing. To start off, here is some code

```
x=linspace(-10, 10, 10000)
t=linspace(0,5,10000)

u=np.exp(-x**2)

k=u*t+x
```

So I take an x array, get the height of that by putting it into the Gaussian, then based on that height, that is the speed at which that x value is propagating through space, which I find with k. My problem is, I need to find when the Gaussian becomes a double-valued function (or in other words, when a shock happens). If I do argmax solution, I will always get the last value in k because it is very close to zero, I need the first value after the element that will give me a double value in my function.

[Edit] Small Example

```
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] #Input 
k=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,10] #adjusted for speed

output I want
in this case, 5 is the first number that goes above a number that comes after it.
So I need to know the index of where 5 is located and possibly the index 
of the number that it is greater than
```

Comment: Could you describe your problem more precisely? As it stands you could simply `print 'Yes'`, since some element in the array is, in fact, greater then or equal to all of the other elements. Are you trying to find the maximum element?

Comment: I guess the biggest thing is finding the index once I know it's greater than a proceeding element.

Comment: Let me try to restate your problem: Given list `A` and index `I`, determine if `A[I]` is larger than all subsequent values in `A`. If not, determine the index of the maximum subsequent value in `A`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first value that is greater than a later value necessarily corresponds to the minimum among local minima:

```
k = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,10])
lm_i = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(k))) > 0)[0] + 1
mlm = np.min(k[lm_i])
mlm_i = lm_i[np.argmin(k[lm_i])]
```

The index of the first value greater than a later value is then the first index greater than that minimum local minimum:

```
i = np.where(k > mlm)[0][0]
```

[image: Plot of solution]

(Ignore that the graph appears to cross the horizontal line at the tangent; that's just a display artefact.)

As a one-liner:

```
np.where(k > np.min(k[np.where(np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(k))) > 0)[0] + 1]))[0][0]
```

Note that this is approx. 1000 times faster than root's solutions, as it is entirely vectorised:

```
%timeit np.where(k > np.min(k[np.where(np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(k))) > 0)[0] + 1]))[0][0]
1000 loops, best of 3: 228 us per loop
```

Comment: Amazing, this was by far the fastest solution. I had to add in a 
try except block because I was getting value errors, but after that it worked fantastically. Thank you!

Comment: You can shave another 25% off with `np.where(k > np.min(k[np.where(np.diff(k) < 0)[0][0]:]))[0][0]` also, you don't really need the `np.min()` call.

Comment: @root the `np.min` is necessary if there could be more than one local minimum.  I like your solution, though; you're finding the global minimum after the first local maximum, which is significantly simpler than considering multiple local minima.

Answer (score 3):

Vectorised solution, that is about 25% faster than ecatmur's:

```
np.where(k > np.min(k[np.where(np.diff(k) < 0)[0][0]:]))[0][0]
```

A naive approach:

```
next(i for i in np.arange(len(arr)) if arr[i:].argmin() != 0)
```

Comment: Still not sure what OP is asking, but it definitely looks like `arr[i:].argmax()` is the solution.

Comment: See my edited question to see why this won't work for me. I did learn something though, so for that I thank you.

Comment: @NightHallow -- Even with your current edit it is quite costly to understand what you are trying to accomplish. Give us a small input sample (say lenght 10) and add the output you want with an explanation...

Comment: @NightHallow -- is this the output you want, or do you want only the indices that are greater than their immediate successors -- in which case it is even simpler...

Comment: I have the code for the immediate successors, so this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
It is actually cheaper to have a 10,000 item python for loop, than operating on a 100,000,000 item array::

```
In [14]: np.where(np.array([True if np.all(k[:j] <= k[j]) else
                            False for j in xrange(len(k))]) == 0)
Out[14]: (array([5129, 5130, 5131, ..., 6324, 6325, 6326]),)

In [15]: %timeit np.where(np.array([True if np.all(k[:j] <= k[j]) else
                                    False for j in xrange(len(k))]) == 0)
1 loops, best of 3: 201 ms per loop
```

---

It's going to be costly as far as memory goes, but you can vectorize the search using broadcasting. If you do:

```
>>> k <= k[:, None]
array([[ True, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False],
       ..., 
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

The return is an array of bools, where the item in position `[i, j]` tells you whether `k[j]` is less than or equal to `k[i]`. When can use `np.cumprod` as follows:

```
>>> np.cumprod(k <= k[:, None], axis=1)
array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1]])
```

where the item in position `[i, j]` tells you whether `k[j]` is less than or equal to all items in `k[:i]`. If you take the diagonal of that matrix:

```
>>> np.cumprod(k <= k[:, None], axis=1)[np.diag_indices(k.shape[0])]
array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1])
```

the item at position `[i]` tells you whether `k[i]` is less than or equal than all items preceeding it. Find where that array is zero:

```
>>> np.where(np.cumprod(k <= k[:, None],
...                     axis=1)[np.diag_indices(k.shape[0])] == 0)
(array([5129, 5130, 5131, ..., 6324, 6325, 6326]),)
```

and you will have the indices of all the values fulfilling your desired condition.

If you are only interested in the first one:

```
>>> np.argmax(np.cumprod(k <= k[:, None],
...                      axis=1)[np.diag_indices(k.shape[0])] == 0)
5129
```

It's not a light operation, but if you have the memory to fit all the boolean arrays, it won't have you waiting too long:

```
In [3]: %timeit np.argmax(np.cumprod(k <= k[:, None],
                                     axis=1)[np.diag_indices(k.shape[0])] == 0)
1 loops, best of 3: 948 ms per loop
```

Comment: Your edit gives me an error, it has to do with a ] being in a wrong spot? I can't get it to work.

Comment: Works now! But the solution I accepted works a little better for what I need it for, but I will more than likely use this solution as well for something different I had planned. Thanks!

Comment: @NightHallow ecatmur's answer is clearly the way to go: good math always beats programming.